# How to redirect to cloud page and then the same link which has been used in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketingcloudapi

We want to use all links to be directed to cloudpage(cloudpage is doing some action), then immediately to the same link(not a specific link) which has been used across email. How would it possible? Any insight will be helpful.

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(pageid, 'redirectTo', 'link'))=%%>link</a>
```

This is not working when put inside every email link.

Cloud page code below.

```
%%[
SET @emailAddress = AttributeValue("Email")
SET @FirstName = AttributeValue("FirstName")
SET @redirectto = RequestParameter(redirectto)

IF NOT EMPTY(@emailAddress) THEN
]%%
    
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
try {
  
    var email = Variable.GetValue("@emailAddress");
    var FirstName = Variable.GetValue("@FirstName");
        //authenticate to get access token
    var authEndpoint = 'subdomain.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/';  //add your tenant specific endpoint
    var payload = {
        client_id: "clientid",            //add your client id
        client_secret:"client_secret",     //add your client secret
        grant_type: "client_credentials"
    };
    var url = authEndpoint + '/v2/token';
    var contentType = 'application/json';

    var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
    if (accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
        var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
        var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token;
        var rest_instance_url = tokenResponse.rest_instance_url;
    };
      //make api call to release subscriber 
    if (email != null && accessToken != null) {
        var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
        var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
        var jsonBody = {
            "ContactKey": email,                      //pass the Contact Key
            "EventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",   //add the  API Key
            "Data": {
                "Email": email,
                "FirstName": FirstName
                
            }
        };
        
        var requestUrl = rest_instance_url + "/interaction/v1/events";
        
        var fireEntryEvent = HTTP.Post(requestUrl, contentType, Stringify(jsonBody), headerNames, headerValues);
                
        };
}
catch (error) {
    Write("<br> something went wrong.<br>" + Stringify(error));
}
</script>
%%[
Redirect(@redirectto)
]%%
%%[ELSE]%%

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Is this the literal implementation? Or are you putting the actual link in the function call? E.g. RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(123, 'redirectTo', 'https://www.example.com')) ?

Comment: Yes Lukas I am putting actually link inside, But it is doing the action in cloud page, but after that It is not redirecting to the email link.

Comment: Please share your CloudPage code in your updated question

Comment: Cloud page code updated - Lukas . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There were few issues in your code.
Also, try redirecting in SSJS instead of in AMPScript:

```
%%[
set @subscriberKey = RequestParameter(_subscriberKey)
set @emailAddress = RequestParameter(emailaddr)
SET @FirstName = AttributeValue("FirstName")
SET @redirectto = RequestParameter("redirectto")
IF NOT EMPTY(@emailAddress) THEN
]%%
    
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1");
try {
  
    var email = Variable.GetValue("@emailAddress");
    var FirstName = Variable.GetValue("@FirstName");
    var redirectto = Variable.GetValue("@redirectto");

        //authenticate to get access token
    var authEndpoint = 'subdomain.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/';  //add your tenant specific endpoint
    var payload = {
        client_id: "clientid",            //add your client id
        client_secret:"client_secret",     //add your client secret
        grant_type: "client_credentials"
    };
    var url = authEndpoint + '/v2/token';
    var contentType = 'application/json';

    var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
    if (accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
        var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
        var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token;
        var rest_instance_url = tokenResponse.rest_instance_url;
    };
      //make api call to release subscriber 
    if (email != null && accessToken != null) {
        var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
        var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
        var jsonBody = {
            "ContactKey": email,                      //pass the Contact Key
            "EventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",   //add the  API Key
            "Data": {
                "Email": email,
                "FirstName": FirstName
                
            }
        };
        
        var requestUrl = rest_instance_url + "/interaction/v1/events";
        
        var fireEntryEvent = HTTP.Post(requestUrl, contentType, Stringify(jsonBody), headerNames, headerValues);
        Platform.Response.Redirect(redirectto)       
        };
}
catch (error) {
    Write("<br> something went wrong.<br>" + Stringify(error));
}
</script>
%%[ELSE]%%
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: Also, @Pravat, I would avoid using email address as contact key, but that's a whole different topic

Comment: Thanks Lukas, But it is still not working and showing 500 -Internal server error.

Comment: OK, I need to see if I can do some tests later

Comment: Hi Lukas, I am able to solve it. Now it is working. But the problem is with the subscriberkey. If I assign the ContactKey as subscriberkey, I am getting error which I should not. If you have any suggestion let me know.